# Centralized REST API call management?

Tags: c#, rest, api, dto

I was given a solution with many projects.  Multiple projects call multiple REST APIs.  These calls are scattered around the spaghetti code.  Trying to figure out what calls are done in what sequence and what dependencies they have is daunting.  Do you know of a way, maybe a design pattern, or a pre-existing tool, that I can use to have all the endpoints in one place and perhaps define their sequences?  For example, we could have:

- One set apiCall1 -> apiCall2 -> apiCall3

vs.

- Another set apiCallA -> apiCall2 -> apiCallB

I don't know the right term to search for, and I don't want to introduce complexity.  I'm trying to simplify it.  I've searched for centralized API management, central REST APIs, but I don't want to provide the APIs, I want to call them.

Each call returns JSON that we extract data and copy into DTOs.

I must use C# in Visual Studio 2017, not Core.

Comment: Can you give us more information about what this code does? Just some high level ideas. What business function does each project serve? Are these APIs unique to each project or at APIs reused between projects?

Comment: And from the sounds of it, "introducing complexity" would be the *least* of my worries. The true complexity in code like this is trying to figure out what it does and what order it gets done.

Comment: Not sure what the downvotes are for.  I wish SO required an explanation, otherwise how can I learn to ask questions better?

Comment: @GregBurghardt, I appreciate your comments.  What the code does is supply a website and also a webservice.  Many REST APIs are called that return JSON that the website/service plop into DTOs and show in UI (app) or send back to caller (service).  I am unsure whether they are unique or shared.  I will need to investigate that.  Regarding the coplexity issue, I hear you!  That's why I'm looking for something to centralize and manage, but I don't want to get wrapped up around the axle of yet another framework to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem space is called service dependencies. Documentation can go a long way, but can also be hard to come by once services are rolled out.

What are you using for service registry or service locator? That might be a path to follow to mine the information you need.

Two technologies have emerged that you can route API calls and through logging and other means can build a service dependency graph:

1. API gateway - Acts as a cross-cutting layer to accept all API calls and route them to the respective services
2. API sidecar (service mesh) - one API proxy per service

Comment: To @Martin - Wow, learned something new.  Thanks!  Sorry do not have the reputation to upvote.

Comment: To @Stackoverflow, Judging by the modernity and and serious, professional software engineering patterns in this answer, I would suggest doing away with downvoting as it does not add value and is actually a negative indication to a positive, useful question and answer.